# Getting a difference between a sum of row from 2 different tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, I am trying to get the sum of the amount paid which is in one table from sum of monthly_cost that is in another table. Its not giving me a result. I need help from you colleagues. Below is the code

```
$sql=mysql_query("select sum(monthly_cost) as overallmc from link");
        $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($aql);   
        $r=mysql_query("select sum(amount_paid) as total  from link_logs where date_of_execution BETWEEN '$sDate1' AND '$sDate2'");  
        $rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($r);

        $ronald=$row['overallmc']- $rows['total'];
        echo $row['overallmc'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a typo in this line:

```
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($aql);
```

It should be:

```
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
```